# In laravel 5.3 when i logout from admin i got "TokenMismatchException"

Tags: php, laravel

In laravel 5.3, I can submit a form from my project when i logged in admin but when I logout from admin and submit the same form without refresh the page I get a **TokenMismatchException**.

My route:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin', 'middleware' => ['backend']], function()
{
    Route::get('logout', 'Auth\LoginController@logout')->name('user.logout');
});
```

My Form:

```
{!! Form::open(['route' => ['contactus.store'], 'method'=> 'POST', 'id' => 'contact_us_form']) !!}

    <?php echo Form::text('name', NULL, ['placeholder' => 'name', 'class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'name']); ?>

{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the right way to resolve token mismatch error in laravel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45223087/what-is-the-right-way-to-resolve-token-mismatch-error-in-laravel)

Comment: What middleware "backend" have ?

Answer (score 1):

If i understood correctly the problem:

- You are logged in as user 'admin';
- You go the form page;
- You logout from admin user;
- Without refreshing the form page, you submit the form and get the TokenMismatchException

In that case, this is the expected behaviour. From the docs:

> This token is used to verify that the authenticated user is the one actually making the requests to the application.

When you logout, your CSFR become invalid: that's why you need to refresh the page.

You can disable them for specific URIs by modifying the `$except` property in `VerifyCsrfToken.php`:

```
class VerifyCsrfToken extends BaseVerifier
{
    /**
     * The URIs that should be excluded from CSRF verification.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $except = [
        'your/route',
    ];
}
```

Comment: is it possible to add route in $except array?
like this route('route-to-something'); ?

Comment: no, you can't put something to evaluate when assigning value to a property outside a function, only constants

Answer (score 0):

Tokens are there SPECIFICALLY to stop you posting the same form TWICE.
If you don't want that behaviour, remove the CSRF token from your form.

Comment: i am opening two tabs when i logout from tab my token will be destroyed , if i returned to the second tab which has the form (without refreshing it ) and submitting the form it will give me this error

Comment: That's kind of expected behaviour!

Comment: @delboy1978uk Do you think its better to show the error message to the user?

Comment: If the error message is only something a dev would understand then use a friendlier message

Answer (score 0):

First, you don't need to care token when the request is `GET`.
Second, when you use `POST` request, you have to save `token` in every request and use it.
The coding way depends on your coding. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

you should add

```
<input type="hidden" value="{{csrf_token()}}" name="_token"/>
```

to your logout form

Comment: This is not necessary since the HTML form builder `Form::open()` will do this for you

Comment: i don't have form in logout, it's a get action.